# Interference of two waves of different frequencies relevance to background noise + sonometer

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, interference

If two sound waves of different frequencies are recorded then does the interference between the two waves of different frequencies alter the resultant frequency recorded.
In better context, I'm currently doing a sonometer experiment for school and I'm trying to analyse how the uncontrolled variable background noise potentially affected the frequency recorded.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the two fundamental frequencies you will also get the [beat frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)) as they interfere in the microphone

Answer (score 0):

So in our results, i found that the frequency recorded in a quiet area was higher than a loud area, varying by around 5Hz.

Can this be attributed to the interfering frequencies?